# Use ob_ in phpUnit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I test controller by unit test. Controller implements some api who return json.
Right to be use ob_ php func. to check return json data for test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPUnit knows how to test output: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.output